# Jump to a specific location on an image map

Tags: javascript, html, image, imagemap

I have a big image with an HTML `<map>`, and I want to jump to a particular region on that image. I have used the `<area />` tag for marking the locations

Take a look at the code :

```html
<img src="demo_files/k3.png" id="target" alt="Map" usemap="#powerpuffgirls" />
<map name="powerpuffgirls">
    <area shape="rect" coords="624,137,671,167" href="#" id="ppg" title="The Powerpuff Girls" alt="The Powerpuff Girls" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="99,2685,161,2723" href="#" name="ppg1" title="The Powerpuff Gidrls" alt="The Powerpuff sGirls" />
</map>
```

however, I am unable to move to any region on the image.

**Edit:** Any other approach for moving to an image's particular region would be great !!

Comment: is that bigger than the screen resolution of the monitor...??

Comment: @SaurabhLP yes, page displaying with both scroll bar !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/55tdu/)

```
$('a.links').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var coor = $(this.hash).attr('coords').split(',');
  $('html,body').scrollTo(coor[0], coor[1]);
});
```

i have used the plugin [scrollTo](http://yckart.github.io/jquery.scrollto.js/)

the script will prevent default function of a tag and will get the coordinates attribute from the area tag with the id from the href attribute and calculate the positions and scroll to that position

Answer (score 0):

Check this **demo** i have created...

Try to navigate the areas by id...

```
<div><a href="#ppg">Go to one</a> <a href="#ppg1">Go to two</a></div>
```

You have to play with the area coordinates in it...

http://jsfiddle.net/D9W6C/

Comment: thanks for your answer but you can see in your example the page is moving on same location, whatever the coordinates given in area..